# How to deal with json string / maps that have date time as their key?

Tags: flutter

I have run into an issue when trying to store data on disk.
When I serialize and deserialize the json.
I do get a list back but I am unable to access its elements.

Here is the function where I print the data.

This is the main class where everything is stored.

```
class UserWeight {
  final String weight;
  // double totalWeight = 0.0; // This is useless for the time being.
  final String date;
  String json;
  List<Map<String, String>> listOfWeights = []; // where all datetime and weights are stored.


  UserWeight({this.weight, this.date});
  
  // Rest of the functions....
}
```

```
  String serialize() {
    json = jsonEncode(listOfWeights);
    print(json);
    print(jsonDecode(json));
    var b = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(json));
    print("START OF LOOP\n");
    for (var i in b) {
      print(i);
    }
    print("END OF B LOOP\n");
    return json;
  }

  read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<Map<String, String>> s =
        jsonDecode(prefs.getString('listOfWeights') ?? "[{}]")
            as List<Map<String, String>>;
    listOfWeights = s;
  }

  saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //String counter = prefs.getString('listOfWeights');
    await prefs.setString('listOfWeights', serialize());
  }
```

Output is :

```
I/flutter ( 4556): START OF LOOP
I/flutter ( 4556): {2021-02-14 00:00:00.000: 25.0}
I/flutter ( 4556): {2021-02-15 00:00:00.000: 50.0}
I/flutter ( 4556): {2021-02-16 00:00:00.000: 25.0}
I/flutter ( 4556): END OF B LOOP
```

I am unable to convert this `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` into `Map<String,String>`.

In the end I want to convert the json decoded thing: eg.

```
[{2021-02-14 00:00:00.000: 25.0}, {2021-02-15 00:00:00.000: 50.0}, {2021-02-16 00:00:00.000: 25.0}]
```

into a `list<map<string,string>>`, like this:

```
[{"2021-02-14 00:00:00.000":"25.0"},{"2021-02-15 00:00:00.000":"50.0"},{"2021-02-16 00:00:00.000":"25.0"}]
```

I am not willing to use sqflite.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with data that you get from JSON and parse it to weight. But first, create separated class (or store list in file with `Weight` class) to store values and make function to parse JSON to `Weight`:

```dart
final weights = [];

class Weight {
  double totalWeight = 0.0;
  final String date;

  Weight(this.totalWeight, this.date);

  factory Weight.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final data = json.entries.first;
    return Weight(json.key, json.value);
  }
}
```

Then:

```dart
weights.addAll(jsonDecode(json).map((weight) => Weight.fromJson(weight)));
```

Comment: what should I do about json.key and json.value. Where do i get the key and value form?

Comment: Where  should I place the ode after "Then: " ?

Comment: I am getting these error with the factory function:

The getter 'key' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Should I change the List<Map<String, String>> listOfWeights = [];
to simply final listOfWeights = []; ?

Comment: List of weights is a list that contains `Weight` entities, it is not a map. `Weight.fromJson` is factory constructor only for one `Weight` unit, it is not can handle all your JSON structure. First of all, you need to decode json and parse result from it with `map`: `jsonDecode(json).map((weight) => Weight.fromJson(weight));`.